# Rendering Problems: One or more layouts are missing the layout_width or layout_height attributes. These are required in most layouts

Tags: android

getting error : One or more layouts are missing the layout_width or layout_height attributes. These are required in most layouts.

in each xml file, even for new project also.

pls provide some solution.

Comment: looks like some problem with your Android Studio installation.

Comment: no its working perfectly fine but as i updated to 3.2.0 studio i think then after it starts coming

Comment: It it worked perfectly fine, then you did not get those problems. As I said, `looks like some problem with your Android Studio installation.`

Answer (score 3):

The issue is resolved by these changes:

1. Close Android Studio
2. Go to C:\Users\UserName.android and rename the build-cache folder to buildcache.bak
3. Go to C:\Users\UserName.AndroidStudio3.2\system and rename these folders

   (1) caches to caches.bak
   (2) compiler to compiler.bak
   (3) compile-server to compile-server.bak
   (4) conversion to conversion.bak
   (5) external_build_system to external_build_system.bak
   (6) frameworks to frameworks.bak
   (7) gradle to gradle.bak
   (8) resource_folder_cache to resource_folder_cache.bak

   Open the Android Studio and open your project again.

Answer (score 1):

As per you error Android Studio's Most view needs some necessary attibutes without them that view can't be created.

in your code you have to put these two attributes:

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

these attribute defines height and width of your view.you can give it by dynamically as per you want.as per below:

```
 android:layout_width="25dp"
 android:layout_height="30dp"
```

dp means density independent pixels.Hope these information surely be usefull to you.

Comment: maulik , it already there in my each layout, so this can't be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need `width` and `height` in every `View` in `.xml`.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView001"
    android:layout_width="100dp" << this line
    android:layout_height="100dp"  << and this line
/>
```

If your are sure that you have all of them,
try to rebuild your project

or press double `Shift`, type `invalidate caches` to execute `invalidate caches and restart` your AndroidStudio.
Or Update/ReInstall it.

Comment: i tired invalidate caches  but that also not working